# mingw: function not found when compiled with -std=c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, popen, stdio

I was trying to compile the code below (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/478960/683218).
The compile went OK, if I compile with

```
$ g++ test.cpp
```

but went wrong when the `-std=c++11` switch is used:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'std::string exec(char*)':
test.cpp:6:32: error: 'popen' was not declared in this scope
     FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
                                ^
```

Any idea what's going on?

(I am using mingw32 gcc4.8.1 from mingw.org, and on WindowsXP64)

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

int main() {}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your *current* problem, but don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it will not work as you expect it to. The reason is because the `EOF` flag will not be set until *after* you try to read from beyond the end of the file, so you will iterate once to many. Instead in your case simply do `while (fgets(...) != 0)`. This is the same when reading from C++ streams as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this happens because `popen` is not standard ISO C++ (it comes from POSIX.1-2001).

You could try with:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -U__STRICT_ANSI__ test.cpp
```

(`-U` cancels any previous definition of a macro, either built in or provided with a `-D` option)

or

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++11 test.cpp
```

(GCC [defines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) `__STRICT_ANSI__` if and only if the `-ansi` switch, or a `-std` switch specifying strict conformance to some version of ISO C or ISO C++, was specified when GCC was invoked)

Playing with the `_POSIX_SOURCE` / `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` macros is a possible alternative (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just add this at the begining:

```
extern "C" FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode);
```

Comment: This worked for popen, but the same doesn't work for pclose. Any clue why?

Comment: @PeDro did you try `extern "C" FILE *pclose(const char *command, const char *mode);`?

Comment: Honestly I am not aware if popen and pclose belong to the same family

Comment: I did, it threw some error. But commenting it worked for me. :)

Comment: @PeDro. should have tried -
extern "C" void pclose(FILE *pipe);

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems an easy solution, but Just add this header :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
```

even if you are compiling using `-std=c++98` it will work.